# Conditional generative models for large numbers of classes

Tags: generative-models, gan

I'm looking for a conditional generative model — could be cGAN or cVAE — that is particularly well suited to large numbers of classes. I'm expecting to require 500+ classes, but so many models are demonstrated using MNIST, or similar, that it's hard to have a good idea of how they'll perform with more than a few classes.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: i'll just point out that very few models at the time of writing actually work on large, diverse datasets such as imagenet, and not without a lot of compute. you might try biggan

Comment: Okay, thanks for the note.